# Extracting piece of data from youtube data API

Tags: android, youtube, gdata

I need to extract little piece of Data from Youtube Data API (with params), but what i have only seen , is that i must parse all data to get it ...

Let's see the example that i need :

URL = http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/2ILsMmZG4VM

> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/2ILsMmZG4VM2007-06-03T12:41:05.000Z2011-08-03T08:29:25.000ZDARKER THAN BLACK OPENING HD:EDIT:
>   First Darker than Black opening. I uploaded this a long time ago and was NOT aware of the poor translations so please don't be upset and just enjoy the music/animation. If the translations really bother you, then watch a different video. Seriously guys...JuN0http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/jun0Film:EDIT:
>   First Darker than Black opening. I uploaded this a long time ago and was NOT aware of the poor translations so please don't be upset and just enjoy the music/animation. If the translations really bother you, then watch a different video. Seriously guys...darker, then, black

And more deep , i can see the part i need , which is the RTSP link :

> ...media:content url='rtsp://v7.cache8.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlT4UZmMuyC2BMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='101' yt:format='6'/

Then what i need to know if exist params to put in the link to extract directly the URL , to not have to parse all the XML .

Thanks for all , and forgive my bad english.

**SOLUTION**:

I have found it thx to Sherif (1 point for you)

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q="2ILsMmZG4VM"&fields=entry(media:group(media:content))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q="2ILsMmZG4VM"&fields=entry(media:content)
```

However [The fields parameter is currently used for experimental features only](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html#fieldssp)

Comment: mmmm near but throws Invalid selector expression at position 5: Invalid path step:entry

Comment: in the example `fields=entry(title,gd:comments,yt:statistics)` so maybe we should try fields=entry(url) ? please try

Comment: it was near , but it needs the videos?q="video_id" for a good end :D

Comment: like this?? let me see the tick :D congratz